# Reading grayscale image in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have gray scale image "lena.bmp". I want read this image in matlab using imread() function. 
When i use code below to read and show image my image is dark (black).

```
    img = imread('lena.bmp');
    imshow(img);
```

But when i use code below, I have no problem to view.

```
    [img map]= imread('lena.bmp');
    imshow(img,map);
```

It seems that my first code doses not reading image in grayscale mode (like what rgb2gray function generate).

My image is as follows:

[image]

What can i do to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the max and min value of the `img` matrix that you get as the output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your image is an "indexed" image. That means it contains integer values which act as "labels" more than anything, and each of those labels is mapped to a colour (i.e. an rgb triplet). Your `map` variable represents that mapping; at row 5 you have the rgb triplet that corresponds to 'label' "5", for instance.

To see what I mean, do `unique(img)` and you'll see that the values of your `img` array are in fact quite regular. The command `rgbplot` can demonstrate the actual colourmap graphically. Run `rgbplot(map)` on your map variable to see the mapping for each of the red green and blue colours.

Now, save and read the image below on your computer as `img2` and compare the array values.

[image]

This image was generated by converting from the "indexed" image you linked to, to a "grayscale" one using photoediting software (the GIMP). The difference is that
in a grayscale image, the pixel values represent actual intensities, rather than integer 'labels'. Imread reads grayscale images as `uint8` images by default, meaning it assigns intensity values to pixels ranging from 0 (black) to 255 (white). Since these values happen to be integers you could still cheat and treat them as 'labels' and force a colour-mapping on them. But if you assign a 'linear map' (i.e. value 1 = intensity 1, value 2 = intensity 2, etc) then your image will look as you would expect.

You'll see that the values from `unique(img2)` are quite different. If you `imshow(img2)` you'll see this displays as you'd expect. If you don't specify a colormap for imshow, it will assume that the map is a linear mapping from the lowest to the highest value in the image array, which explains why your indexed image looked weird, since its values were never supposed to correspond to intensities.

Also try `imagesc(img2)` which will show this but using the "current" colormap. `imagesc` causes the colormap to be "scaled", so that the lowest colour goes to the lowest value in the image, and similarly for the highest.
The default colormap is `jet` so you should see a psychedelic looking image but you should be able to make out lena clearly. If you try `colormap gray` you should see the gray version again. Also try `colormap hot`. Now to make sense of the colormaps, try the `rgbplot` command on them (e.g. `rgbplot(gray)`, `rgbplot(hot)` etc).

So, going back to imshow, imshow basically allows you to display an indexed image, and specify what colormap you want to use to display it. If you don't specify the colormap, it will just use a linear interpolation from the lowest value to the highest as your map. Therefore imshow(img) will show the image pretty much in the same way as imagesc(img) with a gray colormap. And since the values in your first `img` represent evenly spaced 'labels' rather than actual intensities, you'll get a rubbish picture out.

**EDIT:** If you want to convert your indexed image to a grayscale image, matlab provides the `ind2gray` function, e.g.:

```
[img, map] = imread('lena.bmp');
img_gray = ind2gray(img, map);
```

This is probably what you need if you mean to process pixel values as intensities.