# Why Photoshop has different RGB values from Matlab and R?

Tags: r, matlab, photoshop

Here's my question. I have a bmp file and try to get the RGB values of the picture. I used 4 different ways to accomplish that, imread in Matlab, package "bmp" and "pixmap" in R, photoshop. However, for the same pixel point, these 4 methods return slightly different values.

1. imread() in Matlab and read.bmp() in package "bmp" in R return the same values: (155, 92, 75)
2. getChannels() in package "pixmap" in R returns (0.6431535,
   0.3817427, 0.3112033): they seem to be normalized. Dividing the values obtained in point 1 by the range of red channel in the pic
   ([0,241]) gets exactly the same values. And the range of green and blue channel is [0,187] and [0,176].
3. Photoshop returns slightly different values: (160, 95, 77).

Why are these methods returns different RGB values? Any help will be appreciated.

Updated information:

Original image (open with Preview in Mac ox and ps):
[original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMWLH.png)

Matlab imread() and imshow() image:
[Matlab version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJuVV.png)

And I found if I convert the color mode from RGB to CYMK in photoshop, the pic looks much the same as the one in Matlab.

Comment: Can you upload the actual image here?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38468519/reading-grayscale-image-in-matlab/38469926#38469926

Comment: I gues the original BMP image is not stored in RGB24 color format (one byte per color channel). Try: I = imread('QMWLH.bmp'); display size(I), make sure the size is 640x360x3. Save I imwrite(I, 'RGB.bmp'); now open RGB.bmp in Photoshop, and check values. Might also be gamma related...

Comment: Another idia: It might be related to Photoshop display prpopeties. It is unlikelly photoshop canges pixel values, but it might be that Photoshop dispay pixel values in Adobe RGB instead of sRGB. (i.e only dispalyed value is different).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab and R are designed for scientific or technical applications, and will read in an image directly unchanged. Photoshop, however, is designed for aesthetic applications, and cares much more about the overall appearance of a given image. One of the more important things to do with representations of colour in an image is the [colour space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_space) it was acquired in, defining the range (or [gamut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamut)) of representable shades.

Whilst you haven't shown us the image in question, it's very likely that if it lacked an embedded profile, Photoshop assumed your image was in the standard RGB colour space, sRGB. Since your monitor probably has a different gamut, and by default photoshop uses Adobe RGB to represent images (as it's slightly wider than sRGB), it probably converted it silently to the "new" space. As illustrated below, the two are slightly different:

[image: Adobe RGB]

-- and, hence the values reported are slightly different.

In short, if you want to make great holiday snaps, use Photoshop. If you want to do good science, stay the hell away from it.

Comment: Have you acctualy tested it, or is it just an assumption? I tried it (I used relativly old photoshop version), and the RGB values were the same as in Matlab.

Comment: I've tested this on camera images with embedded colour profiles and the RGB values do differ slightly to `imread`. Changing colour profiles (in photoshop) does indeed alter what is reported inphotoshop, but not matlab.

Comment: Thanks! I've change the color mode in photoshop and the RGB values did change with different color mode. I think the RGB values returned by imread() or R is the original unchanged result I wanna get.

Comment: @lilliam.C -- I think you're right too. What was the original source of the image?

Comment: @Landak I don't quite understand what's the meaning of the "original source of the image". The RGB values stored in the bmp file?

Comment: @lilliam.C -- Nope, I meant "A [visible light] camera", or "a CCD attached to a home made optical system", or "a photodiode" -- I know it is possible to embed colour profiles in .bmp files, located in the DIB header, but I think it is only a sensible thing to do when you have a priori knowledge about the sensitivity of the instrument used to obtain the data in the first place.

Comment: @Landak -- Although there is a camera, I am not familiar with the machine. In fact it's a 3D camera. Maybe I should refer to the suppliers for more details.