# octave imread() question. I dont know why are they different

Tags: image, octave

I used 8bit grayscale 256x256 lena picture (figure3).

```
figure; imshow(imread('lena.png'))
figure; imshow(data)
figure; imshow('lena.png')
```

I think same outputs, but they are different outputs:

[image]

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: Are you sure the PNG is 8 bit grayscale? Maybe it's an indexed image instead? Did you try `[data,cm] = imread('lena.png'); imshow(data,cm)`?

Comment: you can try printing the content that imread() returns with `disp data` to see if its what you would expect for 8bit grayscale (a 2d array of values ranging from 0 to 255) or indexed

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I just thought it have 256x 256 data(matrix).

Comment: This question is likely a duplicate of this one: [Reading grayscale image in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38468519/reading-grayscale-image-in-matlab)

Answer (score 2):

From the three different calls to `imshow`, the correct one seems to be the one where you just pass it the filepath.  Reading the sourcecode for `imshow` you will see that it also reads the image colormap.

Seems like you don't have a simple grayscale image but instead you have an indexed image, so you should be doing this instead:

```
[img, cmap] = imread (...);
imshow (img, cmap);
```

By the way, it seems to me that you're trying to pre-allocate the image data. If so, you are doing it wrong.

```
# The pre-allocation with zeros here does nothing. Not only does
# imread creates its own new array, its data type will be uint8 while
# zeros is creating one of doubles by default.
data = zeros(256, 256) ;
data = imread('lena.png');
```